# how to get sql results within current calender week

Tags: mysql

I'm having the this problem below. I'm trying to return all records from my table which are within the current week.

I tried this but it doesn't work out.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sreservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND week(rdate) = week(now()) UNION
SELECT * FROM preservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND week(rdate) = week(now()) UNION
SELECT * FROM greservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND week(rdate) = week(now()) ORDER BY rdate";
```

I do have two tables *users* is the table where the login data is stored and *reservation* is the table where all reservations made by the user is stored. *rdate* stores the reservation date. If this date is within the current week it should be shown. Unfortunately it isn't working.

The filtering for today's and tomorrow's reservation is working properly

**Today**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sreservation AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY UNION
SELECT * FROM preservation AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY UNION
SELECT * FROM greservation AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY rdate";
```

**Tomorrow**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sreservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() UNION 
SELECT * FROM preservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() UNION
SELECT * FROM greservation WHERE user_fk = $user AND DATE(rdate) = CURDATE() ORDER BY rdate";
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sreservation WHERE WEEK(rdate) = WEEK(CURDATE());";
```

Comment: While this solution does filter on the right right interval provided there is data from one year only and it will not perform well on large dataset, as it cannot use indexes. Better to determine current week's start and end dates and do a between .. and ... search.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working properly.